# Can I display Maven 2 build profile in packaged code?

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a task to add the Maven project version (snapshot, 1.1 etc.) and the Maven profile with which the app was built/packaged to the footer of our Java webapp pages. The first part is easy enough to implement using resource filtering: I create a `project.version=${project.version}` line in a  resource file and using the resources plugin I overwrite the placeholder with the version. This works fine and I can reference `project.version` anywhere I need it. Can I do something similar to show the maven profile with which the app was build/packaged?

Answer (score 2):

There is a property `${project.activeProfiles[0].id}` that probably does what you expect.
There is also this [plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/active-profiles-mojo.html) that can output some information about the profile in a file.

M.